# cakephp rediect to external url in routes.php

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

In Cakephp **routes.php**,
How to redirect to external url
eg: http://blog.example.com

```
Router::connect('/blog','http://blog.example.com/');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done with CakePHP. Well actually it could, but you'd better put this in your .htaccess/apache/nginx/whatever server you're using, this is where this kind of thing belongs.

If you really, really, REALLY can't do it that way, you can route /blog to a controller action that will simply redirect.

```
Config/routes.php
<?php

Router::redirect('/blog/*', 'http://blog.example.com', ['status' => 301]);
```

Edited with may comment

Comment: he can use just the Routes::redirect instead of Routes::connect , http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: I didn't even know this method existed in the Router, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Router::redirect('/blog/*', 'http://blog.example.com', array('status' => 302));
```

here is the cakephp reference . 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing